# How to look up specific columns and copy paste corresponding columns in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate a task in Excel where I need to automate the copying and pasting of certain columns and populate our data in a separate data table file. I have the basic code of reading through multiple Excel files and extracting data, as well as copy pasting. Should have been easy but there are specific required data columns in each file where they are not found in the same index.

[image: Sample Data]

If you see the image above, you will see that different project names. The data required for copy/pasting is determined by its file name. What I wanted to happen was to run the code in such a way that it will reference the file name, then look up columns to find which columns to copy from, and then it will be pasted in the data table. How do I set up the code to run that way?

The code is found below:

```
    Private Const sPath As String = "C:\Users\angj2339\Documents\SSE\New folder\New folder\" 'DIRECTORY PATH

Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Dim sFile As String 'File Name
Dim sExt As String 'File extension you wish to open

    sExt = "xlsm" 'Change this if extension is different

    'loop through each file name and open it if the extension is correct
    sFile = Dir(sPath)
    Do Until sFile = ""
        If Right(sFile, 4) = sExt Then GetInfo sFile
        sFile = Dir
    Loop


End Sub

Private Sub GetInfo(sFile As String)

Dim wbFrom As Workbook 'workbook to copy the data from
Dim iRow As Integer 'row number of next empty row

 On Error GoTo errHandle

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wbFrom = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile)


        wbFrom.Sheets("HighLevelDetail").Range("H4:BQ120").Copy 'Copy H4:BQ120
        iRow = Me.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Get an empty row in this workbook
        Me.Range("A" & iRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'past copied cells
        wbFrom.Close (False)

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wbFrom = Nothing

Exit Sub
errHandle:
MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I will be glad to provide more details or clarify if there are parts of the  question that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Actually there is no question. And now that you described what you want, what is the issue to do it? Where exactly did you get stuck? Why can't you solve your issue? Also you should [edit] your question and include your code as well as your attempt to solve your issue.

Comment: hi, edited the post :)